# Autohotkey (v2): Mark dynamically selected variable as global

Tags: global-variables, autohotkey

How can I modify a global variable from within a function, where I want to select the global variable based on another variable?

Here is sample code for what I have so far:

```
keylist = 1234567890qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnmäüöß,.-

Loop, parse, keylist  
{
    Counter_%A_LoopField% := 0
}

MyFunction(key){
    global Counter_%key%
    Counter_%key% += 1
}
```

This gives the following error:

> Error at line 9. The following variable name contains an illegal
> character: "Counter_%key%"
>
> The program will exit.

Can this be done in AutoHotkey?

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo arrays should be left where they belong, which is code written in 2005.

If I understood what you want correctly, it seems like to me that an input hook and a map is the obvious solution:

```
KeyCounter := Map()

ih := InputHook("L0 V")
ih.OnChar := OnChar
ih.Start()
return

OnChar(ih, key)
{
    global KeyCounter
    KeyCounter[key] := KeyCounter.Has(key) ? KeyCounter[key] + 1 : 1
}


;show counts
F1::
{
    global KeyCounter
    counts := ""
    for key, value in KeyCounter
        counts .= key ": " value "`n"

    MsgBox(counts)
}
```

Comment: I didn't even know Autohotkey has these classes. Seems almost like a different language than the docs I went through. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So I've solved it using arrays now; a bit complicated but it seems to work:

```
Counters := []
keylist := "1234567890qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnmäüöß,.-"

ObjIndexOf(obj, item)  
{
    for i, val in obj {
        if (val == item)   
            return i
    }
    ;MsgBox("item not found: " . item)
}


Loop Parse, keylist
{
    Counters.Push(0)  
}

Loop Parse, keylist
{
    Hotkey("$" A_LoopField, GivenKeyPress)
}
Return 


GivenKeyPress(Key_Name)
{
    key := StrReplace(Key_Name, "$" )
    idx := ObjIndexOf(keylist_list , key)
    global Counters
    Counters[idx] += 1
    return
}
```

Credits to [Coco-guest](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=10507)